# Is there a quantum analogue of the Cauchy stress tensor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

In fluid dynamics, the Cauchy stress-tensor $\sigma$ basically dictates most of the dynamics as

$$\frac{D\mathbf{p}}{D t}=\nabla\cdot \sigma+\ldots$$

Where the stress tensor is $\sigma$, and all other forces are bundled up inside the "$\ldots$" term, which I will ignore.

My question is simple: **is there a (non-relativistic) analogue of the stress tensor in quantum mechanics or QFT?** If so, what do its properties look like? Are there analogues to Newton's law of viscosity and the associated classification of liquids (Newtonian, dilatant, pseudo-plastic, Bingham plastics, etc.)?

For example, I imagine this concept would be relevant in studying quantum fluids of electrons in solids (graphene, gold, etc.) or in quantum theories of elasticity (phonons).

I know the stress tensor does come up in discussions of curved spacetimes, but I am more curious about the simpler case of flat spacetime.

Comment: Why not? When you quantize, all the classical fields you had (which includes the stress tensor) become quantum fields.

Comment: Regarding your last point, the stress tensor isn't at all specific to curved spacetime. It's just a general thing you can compute in almost any field theory, classical or quantum, relativistic or not.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks for the comment! I've edited the question to emphasize I'd like to know more about the quantum Cauchy stress tensor properties. I don't see the formalism in use in many textbooks or papers, unlike in fluid dynamics, which is curious to me.

Comment: You might find this helpful: M. Geracie, K. Prabhu, M. M. Roberts, *Physical stress, mass, and energy for non-relativistic matter*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06729